# Homebrew from within ruby's kernel.system

Tags: ruby, homebrew

I'm trying to issue a homebrew shell command from within a ruby script.

I can issue homebrew shell commands just fine.  For example, this works with no problem:

```
$ brew list | head -n 1
ack
```

I can also issue shell commands from ruby just fine:

```
$ bundle exec ruby -e "Kernel.system('echo foo')"
foo
```

However, when I issue homebrew shell commands from ruby, I get a bundler-related error:

```
bundle exec ruby -e "Kernel.system('brew list')"
Your bundle is locked to bubs (0.0.6), but that version could not be found in any of the sources listed in your Gemfile. If you haven't changed sources, that means the author of bubs (0.0.6) has removed it. You'll need to update your bundle to a different version of bubs (0.0.6) that hasn't been removed in order to install.
```

This happens with even the smallest possible Gemfile (which gem it is doesn't matter).

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'bubs'
```

So, some subset of homebrew, ruby, bundler, and maybe rvm (which is how my ruby is currently installed) isn't play nicely together.

Any idea why I might be getting this error, and/or how I can get homebrew commands to work from ruby?

Comment: `brew` is written in ruby, there is a gemsets conflict. I bet omitting `bundle exec` in front of the command would work: `ruby -e "Kernel.system('brew list')"`.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is just a test case- I can't remove the `bundle exec` in the real project.  The overall thing I'm building is a gem that relies on another tool.  If the other tool isn't installed, it attempts to `brew install` it.  The gem I'm building, like many gems, is built using bundler and uses bundler heavily.

As for a gemset conflict, something like that seems possible.  However, it doesn't seem to actually matter what gems are listed.  The example Gemfile in my question, for example, just uses a single tiny gem I chose at random with no dependensice.

Comment: Once again: this is a **`gemset`** conflict between `brew`, that is written in ruby, and your application. Of course, it does not depend on what gems are listed in your `Gemfile`. You might try to play with running `brew` in the new shell that does not derive the environment of the current one, or like.

Comment: I'm not sure I entirely follow you.  I was under the impression that gemsets were an RVM thing, unless there's some other usage of the term that I'm not aware of.  As far as I know, I'm not explicitly using a gemset, and `rvm gemset list` says it's set to `(default)`.  Since brew works even without rvm (you can install it using the system ruby), I don't see what it would be doing with a gemset in the first place.

Comment: `brew` has [it’s own `Gemfile`](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/blob/master/Library/Homebrew/cask/Gemfile), as well as _any other ruby application, that uses external dependencies_. `rvm`/`rbenv` is just a manager to handy switch gemsets / rubies. `bundle exec` instructs ruby to set a gemset for this particular session to _this directory’s `.bundle/config`_. `brew.sh` in turn resets everything to it’s `gemset`. I would recommend you to read a documentation on `bundler` and `gem` utilities.

Comment: I do not post this as an answer since I do not consider MacOS being applicable for any kind of development, hence fighting it’s glitches like that simply makes not much sense IMHO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer after some searching: wrap any shelling out you do in bundler in `Bundler.with_clean_env`.  Eg: `bundle exec ruby -e "Bundler.with_clean_env { Kernel.system('brew list') }"` will work.

Bundler provides a shortcut for something like that: `Bundler.clean_system('brew list')`.

From the docs: http://bundler.io/v1.13/man/bundle-exec.1.html#Shelling-out